# ggplot: how to get legend linetype group-dependent while errorbar linetype solid

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to plot lines representing observations from two groups, `y1` and `y2` in a way that:

- the two groups have different line color (marked on legend)
- the two groups have different linetype (marked on legend)
- the plot has errorbar, and error bar is solid line in **both** groups

Code generating some data:

```
## generate data 
x.grid <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 6)
y1.func <- function(x) 1/(x+1)
y2.func <- function(x) 2/(x+3)

set.seed(1)
x.vec <- numeric()
y.vec <- numeric()
group.vec <- numeric()
for (x in x.grid){
  x.vec <- c(x.vec, rep(x, 2*10))
  y.vec <- c(y.vec, 
             rep(y1.func(x), 10) + rnorm(10, sd = 0.1),
             rep(y2.func(x), 10) + rnorm(10, sd = 0.1))
  group.vec <- c(group.vec, rep("y1", 10), rep("y2", 10))
}
plt.df <- data.frame(x = x.vec, y = y.vec, group = group.vec)

## summarize data 
plt.df.se <- Rmisc::summarySE(plt.df, measurevar = "y", groupvars=c("x", "group"))
```

**Approach 1:**

```
ggplot2::ggplot(plt.df.se,
       aes(x = x, 
           y = y, 
           color = group,
           linetype = group)) + 
  geom_line(position=pd, size = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-se, ymax=y+se), width=.05, 
                position=position_dodge(0.05), linetype = 1)
```

[image]
**bad**: legend blue not dashed

**Approach 2:**

```
ggplot2::ggplot(plt.df.se,
       aes(x = x, 
           y = y, 
           color = group,
           linetype = group)) + 
  geom_line(position=pd, size = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-se, ymax=y+se), width=.05, 
                position=position_dodge(0.05))
```

[image]
**bad**: blue error bars are dashed (I want them solid)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, you only want the linetype aesthetic to apply to your lines, so don't include it in the top-level aesthetic mapping, only in `geom_line()`. Then use `show.legend = FALSE` in `geom_errorbar()` so it won't affect the legends:

```
ggplot(plt.df.se,
                aes(x = x, 
                    y = y, 
                    color = group)) + 
    geom_line(aes(linetype = group), position=position_dodge(0.05), size = 0.5) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-se, ymax=y+se), width=.05, 
                  position=position_dodge(0.05),
                  show.legend = FALSE)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You are very right! Thank you a ton for helping out.